# Why words count mismatching with read word count?

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code for speed reading simulation. 
Its working fine. But i have pasted 500 words into the box, after read all the words, words count is differing from the input words count.

```js
$('#sim').each(function(){
        this.contentEditable = true;
    });
    
    var go = $('#go');
    var stop = $('#stop');
    var wordCount = 0;
    var wordCountBox = $('#wordCountBox');
    var timepassed = $('#timepassed');
    var textRead = $('#textRead');
    
    
    go.on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        startSim();
    });
    
    function startSim(){
        var speed = $('#speed').val();
        timeStart = $.now();
        var sim = $('#sim').text();
        var wordArray = sim.split(" ");
        var simWrap = $('#sim');
        
        var arrCount = wordArray.length;
        var alreadyRead = [];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < arrCount; i++) {
            (function(index) {
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    var pos = index;
                    if(pos < 0){
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    alreadyRead.push(wordArray[pos]);
                    wordArray[pos] = '<b>'+wordArray[pos]+'</b>';
                    var words = wordArray.join(" ");
                    simWrap.html(words);                
                    wordCount++;
                    if(pos == (arrCount - 1)){
                        triggerDone();
                    }
                }, i * speed);
             })(i);
        }
        // Function done
        function triggerDone(){
            wordCountBox.text(wordCount+' Words Read');
            var timeEnd = $.now();
            var timeRes = timeEnd - timeStart;
            timeRes = parseInt(timeRes);
            timeRes = timeRes / 1000;
            timepassed.text(timeRes+" seconds have passed");
            alreadyRead = alreadyRead.join("");
            textRead.text(alreadyRead);
            var summary = $('#summary');
            summary.show();
            return;
        } 
        stop.on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            triggerDone();
        });
    }
```

```css
#sim{
        width:800px;
        height:300px;
        border:solid 1px #2e2e2e;
        color:#2e2e2e;
        padding:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:9px outset #0ADA0A;
    margin-top:1em;
    }
```

```html
<div id="sim"></div>
```

Why it is calculating the words count?

And One more doubt, how to auto scroll, when reading the words.

Could Someone please solve this?

Comment: Can you put the code on jsFiddle(jsfiddle.net/)? It would speed tracking the problem.

It's a loooooong shot, but i'm thinking it's related to the breaking on spaces line.

Comment: Hi @Renato. This code: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lwm6gh1/40/

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is with:

`var wordArray = sim.split(" ");`

In this case, it's creating a new "word" for the array each time a space is encountered... so a string like:

`var words = "foo bar bim   baz";`

Will return and array with a length of 6. Use regex...

`var wordArray = sim.split(/\s+/);`

.. and it will solve this problem.

Comment: it selects all the words at a time.

Comment: [No it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lwm6gh1/44/). However, I am noticing that as @Renato mentioned in his comment that the line breaks are an issue. I'll update the post.

Comment: sorry, that was the problem. now its working good.. Thanks @wahwahwah.

Comment: And how to auto scroll, when reading the texts. i am scrolling manually in reading.

Comment: You don't need to put `\s` inside `[ ]`. You can just use `\s+`

Comment: i am using this code: jsfiddle.net/8Lwm6gh1/40/. how can i see reading text, after cross the border height?